# node-postgres gives “Error: timeout expired”

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have this super simple `node-postgres` example that I just can’t get to run:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')

const postgresOptions = {
  connectionString: 'postgres://REDACTED:REDACTED@hattie.db.elephantsql.com/REDACTED',
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000
}

const runDatabaseFunction = async function (functionToRun) {
  // Connect db
  const client = new Client(postgresOptions)
  await client.connect() // Here’s where it times out after 10 seconds
  // Run function
  // const results = await functionToRun(client)
  // Release db
  await client.end()
  return results
}

async function dbTest () {
  const result = await runDatabaseFunction()
}

dbTest()
```

After 10000 milliseconds, it times out at `await client.connect()` with this error:

```
(node:80229) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: timeout expired
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/REDACTED/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:95:26)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
    at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning (internal/process/promises.js:168:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:247:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
```

Why?! Any tips are helpful.

- Same issues with both Heroku Postgres and ElephantSQL.
- Connecting with `psql` or Postico for Mac works just fine, same connection string.

Comment: Probably a firewall problem.  But what happens if you use psql to connect to the same URL?

Comment: Haven't tried `psql` but Postico for Mac works just fine with same connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turned out to be an old version of `pg`.** I expanded my search to Node.js/Postgres issues and found [this comment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2413#issuecomment-730032661).

So upgrading:

```
"pg": "^8.7.1",
```

…I got it to work for ElephantSQL. Heroku Postgres still struggled with SSL issues, but by adding this to the config:

```
const postgresOptions = {
  // ...
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
}
```

…I got Heroku Postgres to work too.

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt the connection string be without "DATABASE_URL=" :

```
  connectionString: 'postgres://REDACTED:REDACTED@hattie.db.elephantsql.com/REDACTED',
```

Comment: Ah that was a typo, it wasn't in the real code, updated my example now. Thanks for spotting. Error remains though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the db port here.

Small suggesion. As per the docs you can specify the client configs individually which is in my opinion more readable and more configurable (if you want you can externalize the configs later). So you can define the cofigs as below.

```
const client = new Client({
  host: 'my.database-server.com',
  port: 5334,
  user: 'database-user',
  password: 'secretpassword!!',
})
```

Refer here: [pg Client docs](https://node-postgres.com/api/client)

Apart from that, you have to pass a calle function to `runDatabaseFunction()`so that it can be referenced as `fucntionToRun` in your code where I don't see it. Otherwise though you could connect to the database successfully by fixing the `timeout error` you will get a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: I added the port 5432 (same as Postico client) like this `connectionString: 'postgres://REDACTED:REDACTED@hattie.db.elephantsql.com:5432/REDACTED'` but same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your db host is up and running? Because I tried out the same code connecting to one of my db cluster and it's working fine when I comment out `const results = await functionToRun(client)` line. Because you haven't provided any function there and you will get a reference error.

Comment: Yes, because connecting with Postico for Mac works just fine.